# SSIS packages not showing in Upgrade Wizard Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I am having an issue upgrading our existing 2017 SSIS packages to 2019 . I have updated the target server version in the package settings and we have installed all the necessary SSDT files from what I can tell. When I go through the upgrade wizard none of the packages show in "select packages" step. I've tried it for a number of different packages all with the same result.

Comment: I'm not certain of what I'm about to say, hence I'm posting as a comment and not an answer, but your question is a couple of days old so I'll give it a shot: Do you have any script tasks in your package? If not, then, IIRC, there's nothing to migrate. You just set the target server version and you're done, ready to deploy to your new server.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere by Microsoft that the upgrade wizard is only for changing SSIS package formats and the last time that occurred was going to packageformat 8 (which I think is 2016 version).  Bottom line is they said this tool doesn't do anything after 2016 SSIS.  Be nice if they documented that in the upgrade wizard documentation!